# adding robot_description to parameter server

Tags: urdf, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'd like to add robot_description to parameter server and frankly speaking, after reading the tutorial about making urdf, I still have no idea, how to do that.

In my launch file I did:

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    **<remap from="robot_description" to="$(find museumGuide)/urdf_model/peoplebot.xml" />**

    <remap from="joint_state" to="joint_state"/>
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="15.0"/>
    <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value=""/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

But apparently this line **remap from="robot_description" to="$(find museumGuide)/urdf_model/peoplebot.xml" /** is wrong, as I get error:

```
remap to [/home/peoplebot/fuerte_wrkspc/sandbox/museumGuide/urdf_model/peoplebot.xml] is not a valid ROS name
```

I'd be gratefull for your help!
Thanks in advance,

da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61479/adding-robot_description-to-parameter-server/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `remap` command is only used to "rename" parameters that are already loaded to the parameter server.  In your case, you want to load new data to the parameter server, so you'll need to do something different.

There are multiple ways to load URDF data from a file to the parameter server:

1. Use `<param>` with the `command` attribute, as shown in [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher#Launch_File) URDF tutorial:
2. Use `<param>` with the `<textfile>` argument as shown [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/param):

I think it is generally preferred to use option #2.  That's also the method that is used for packages generated by the internal ROS wizards for [Arm Navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard) and [MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start).

**Edit:**
In response to Cerin's comment below, here's a 3rd option showing how to load an XACRO file to the parameter server:

3. Use `<param>` with the `command` attribute and the `xacro` script, as shown in the very first example on the [XACRO Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File) page:

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-04-24**:
Thank you, it worked :)

**Comment by [Satoshi Iwashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8741/satoshi-iwashi/) on 2013-11-19**:
thanks it worked me too!

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-06-06**:
How can we do this using 'rosparam load'?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-18**:
How would you load a urdf xacro file/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm late to the game, but an alternative way to add a `robot_description` to the parameter server is through the command line

```
rosparam load my_robot.urdf robot_description
```

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_load), the syntax

```
rosparam load <yaml-file> [namespace]
```

is for a `yaml` file, but this works just as well with a `urdf` file. The wiki does have a warning though

> NOTE: this will add to the currently set values.

I tried loading it twice to see if I would get the two descriptions loaded under one parameter and I didn't.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1